# Modify JSON properties with T-SQL in SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, json, sql-server-2016

Lets say I have JSON data :

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(4000)
SET @json = 
N'{
    "info":{  
      "type":1,

      "address":{  
        "town":"Bristol",
        "county":"Avon",
        "country":"England"
      },
      "tags":["Sport", "Water polo"]
   },
   "type":"Basic"
}'
```

Is there any standard way to manipulate JSON properties in SQL Server 2016 T-SQL (add new, rename, remove), something similar to what JObject offers?

Comment: You mean like [`JSON_MODIFY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-modify-transact-sql), as documented in the Fine Manual?

Comment: Bingo, at first glance it looked like you can modify only values, not properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To modify data, it is necessary to use the JSON_MODIFY statement with the JSON file as an input, as well as a necessary property and a new value.
It's quite easy.
If you want to add a new value to the data array, you can use the key word **append**. If you want to delete any property in the file, you need to specify the null value in the lax mode.
You can find also code samples on this page http://codingsight.com/sql-server-2016-json-data-modification-part-4/

Answer (score 3):

To answer my own question, with [JSON_MODIFY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-modify-transact-sql) I was able to add, delete properties.

"Rename" can be achieved by combining [JSON_VALUE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-value-transact-sql) & [JSON_MODIFY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-modify-transact-sql) methods, essentially adding new property with old data, and then deleting old property.

Snippet :

```
-- Rename propety
DECLARE @stats NVARCHAR(100)='{"click_count": 173}'
PRINT @stats
SET @stats= JSON_MODIFY(JSON_MODIFY(@stats,'$.click_count_new', JSON_VALUE(@stats,'$.click_count')) ,'$.click_count', NULL)
PRINT @stats
```